# Custom dictionary not setting value on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-5

The following code below works perfectly on iPhone 6 and 5S simulator, but when I try to run this code on iPhone 5 simulator these lines of code don't work.

```
self.groupCollection[creditCadKey] = creditCard
self.groupCollection[homeKey] = home
self.groupCollection[boletoKey] = boleto
```

The dictionary simply doesn't change its value, it remains empty. I have no clue why this is going on. Here the full code:

```
import Foundation

public class Checkout_GroupedPaymentSystem : NSObject {
    public var creditCard: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var home: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var voucher: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var boleto: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?

    public let creditCadKey = "Cartão de Crédito"
    public let homeKey = "Pagamento em Casa"
    public let voucherKey = "Voucher"
    public let boletoKey = "Boleto Bancário"

    public var groupCollection: [String:[Checkout_PaymentSystem]] = [:]

    public init(fromDictionary dictionay: NSDictionary) {

        if let creditCardArray = dictionay[creditCadKey] as? [NSDictionary]{
            creditCard = [Checkout_PaymentSystem]()
            for dic in creditCardArray {
                let value = Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: dic)
                creditCard?.append(value)
            }
            self.groupCollection[creditCadKey] = creditCard
        }


         if let homeArray = dictionay[homeKey] as? [NSDictionary]{
            home = [Checkout_PaymentSystem]()
            for dic in homeArray {
                let value = Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: dic)
                home?.append(value)
            }

            self.groupCollection[homeKey] = home
        }

        if let voucherArray = dictionay[voucherKey] as? [NSDictionary]{
            voucher = [Checkout_PaymentSystem]()
            for dic in voucherArray {
                let value = Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: dic)
                voucher?.append(value)
            }

            //self.groupCollection[voucherKey] = voucher
       }

        if let boletoArray = dictionay[boletoKey] as? [NSDictionary]{
            boleto = [Checkout_PaymentSystem]()
            for dic in boletoArray {
                let value = Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: dic)
                boleto?.append(value)
            }

            self.groupCollection[boletoKey] = boleto
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not different versions of iOS ? What iOS version are you using on each simulator ? Try printing the dictionary parameter of init to make sure you have the same entry every time.

Comment: I'm using iOS 9.3 in all simulators. Also, the dictionary it's always the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much... much easier way of doing all this:

```
import Foundation

public class Checkout_GroupedPaymentSystem : NSObject {
    public static let creditCardKey = "Cartão de Crédito"
    public static let homeKey = "Pagamento em Casa"
    public static let voucherKey = "Voucher"
    public static let boletoKey = "Boleto Bancário"

    public var creditCards: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var homes: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var vouchers: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?
    public var boletos: [Checkout_PaymentSystem]?

    public var groupCollection: [String:[Checkout_PaymentSystem]] = [:]

    public init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        guard let creditCardArray = dictionary[creditCardKey] as? [NSDictionary],
            let homeArray = dictionary[homeKey] as? [NSDictionary],
            let voucherArray = dictionary[voucherKey] as? [NSDictionary],
            let boletoArray = dictionary[boletoKey] as? [NSDictionary]else {
            fatalError("One of these is nil or is the wrong type.")
        }

        self.creditCards = creditCardArray.map{ Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: $0) }
        self.homes = homeArray.map{ Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: $0) }
        self.vouchers = voucherArray.map{ Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: $0) }
        self.botelo = boletoArray.map{ Checkout_PaymentSystem(fromDictionary: $0) }

        self.groupCollection = [
            creditCardKey: self.creditCards,
            homeKey: self.creditCards,
            voucherKey: self.creditCards,
            boletoKey: self.creditCards,
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I still facing the same problem with this solution, also, the dictionary parameter at the init may be nil or have some nil keys.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problems?